# Header back button disappears on stand alone build

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I build a stand alone android app the header left back button disappears, yet it's there if you click on it. It has no issue on the emulator. What could cause this?

I'm not sure when it started because I was relying on the emulator, but I do know that it was working at some point

Here is my `app.json`

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "displayName": "appname",
  "expo": {
    "name": "appname",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "slug": "appslug",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "enabled": true,
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 30000,
      "checkAutomatically": "ON_LOAD"
    },
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
      "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
      "bundleIdentifier": "my.unique.id"
      //      "splash": {
      //        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      //        "resizeMode": "cover",
      //        "image": "./assets/iphone/Default-667h@2x.png"
      //      }
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 1,
      "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
      "package": "my.unique.id",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
      //      "splash": {
      //        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      //        "resizeMode": "cover",
      //        "mdpi": "./assets/android/res/drawable-mdpi/background.9.png",   // natural sized image (baseline),
      //        "hdpi": "./assets/android/res/drawable-hdpi/background.9.png",   // scale 1.5x
      //        "xhdpi": "./assets/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/background.9.png",  // scale 2x
      //        "xxhdpi": "./assets/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/background.9.png", // scale 3x
      //        "xxxhdpi": "./assets/android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/background.9.png" // scale 4x
      //      }
    },
    "hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "my.org",
            "project": "proj",
            "authToken": "************"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "primaryColor": "#fefefe"
  }
}
```

And here is my `App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Font, Icon } from 'expo';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Sentry  from 'sentry-expo';

// Remove this once Sentry is correctly setup.
Sentry.enableInExpoDevelopment = true;

Sentry.config('https://sentry').install();


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'Roboto': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <AppNavigator />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        require('./assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        require('./assets/images/robot-prod.png'),
      ]),
      Font.loadAsync({
        // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
        ...Icon.Ionicons.font,
        // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free
        // to remove this if you are not using it in your app
        'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
      }),
    ]);
  };

  _handleLoadingError = error => {
    // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
    // reporting service, for example Sentry
    console.warn(error);
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

`/navigation/MainTabNavigator.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import NotificationScreen from '../screens/NotificationScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';
import ProfileScreen from "../screens/ProfileScreen";
import DraftScreen from "../screens/DraftScreen";
import StatsScreen from "../screens/StatsScreen";
import Colors from "../constants/Colors";
import ViewStoryScreen from "../screens/ViewStoryScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "../screens/RegisterScreen";
import MyStoriesScreen from "../screens/MyStories";
import EditStoryScreen from "../screens/EditStoryScreen";
import AddStoryScreen from "../screens/AddStoryScreen";

const headerStyle = {
  /* The header config from HomeScreen is now here */
  /*
   For full list of options
   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-for-screens-inside-of-the-navigator
    */
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.headerBackgroundColor,
    },
    headerTintColor: Colors.headerTintColor,
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    headerBackTitleStyle: {color: Colors.headerTintColor},
    headerBackStyle: {color: Colors.headerTintColor},
    headerBackAllowFontScaling: true,

  },
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
      Home: HomeScreen,
      ViewStoryScreen: ViewStoryScreen,
      EditStory: EditStoryScreen,
      AddStory: AddStoryScreen,
    },
    {
      /* The header config from HomeScreen is now here */
      defaultNavigationOptions: headerStyle.defaultNavigationOptions
    }
);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
      <TabBarIcon
          focused={focused}
          name={
            Platform.OS === 'ios'
                ? `ios-home`
                : 'md-home'
          }
      />
  ),
};

const NotificationStack = createStackNavigator({
      Links: NotificationScreen,
      ViewStoryScreen: ViewStoryScreen,
    },
    {
      /* The header config from HomeScreen is now here */
      defaultNavigationOptions: headerStyle.defaultNavigationOptions
    });

NotificationStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Notifications',
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
      <TabBarIcon
          focused={focused}
          name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-notifications' : 'md-notifications'}
      />
  ),
};

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
      Settings: SettingsScreen,
      Profile: ProfileScreen,
      Drafts: DraftScreen,
      Stats: StatsScreen,
      Login: LoginScreen,
      Register: RegisterScreen,
      MyStories: MyStoriesScreen,
      ViewStoryScreen: ViewStoryScreen,
      EditStory: EditStoryScreen,
      AddStory: AddStoryScreen,
    },
    {
      /* The header config from HomeScreen is now here */
      defaultNavigationOptions: headerStyle.defaultNavigationOptions
    }
);

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
      <TabBarIcon
          focused={focused}
          name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-options' : 'md-options'}
      />
  ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  NotificationStack,
  SettingsStack,
});
```

**Solution** 
As @Masuk Helal Anik mentioned this is a [bug](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2918) 
Here is what worked for me, but had to sacrifice header back title.
In every screen add this

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {

      headerLeft: (
          <Ionicons
              name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-arrow-back" : "md-arrow-back"}

              size={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 35 : 24}
              color={Colors.headerTintColor}
              style={
                Platform.OS === "ios"
                    ? { marginBottom: -4, width: 25, marginLeft: 9 }
                    : { marginBottom: -4, width: 25, marginLeft: 20 }
              }
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.goBack();
              }}
          />
      ),
      title: 'Screen Title'
    }
  };
```

Comment: You have to provide some more details

Comment: Can you provide the code? And please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik I don't know what caused it and how to solve it. What details would you like so I can add them?

Comment: @AjayGupta Which file would like me to add?

Comment: Provide your package.json, App.js(If it's possible)

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik Just added them

Comment: @STIKO Can I see your navigation part?

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik Added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like a bug. As a solution in this [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2918) is stated

> if you use expo you should include the assets from react-navigation in
>   your assetBundlePatterns so the images are bundled with your app when
>   you build a standalone app. the easiest way to do this is to just
>   bundle all assets that your app uses:
>   https://github.com/expo/new-project-template/blob/6d4c5636de573852dfd2f7715cfa152fd9c84f89/app.json#L20-L22.
>   to fix it in development mode within expo, you can cache the assets
>   locally as per this guide. we do this in the navigationplayground
>   example app, so you can copy that code from here.

There is some workaround also. Try out them to find which one working for you!

Comment: Thanks! The idea of work around in the issue works, but not where they specified it. I'll add what worked for me